# Music information on the iPhone lock screen

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, sdk, mpnowplayinginfocenter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iOS: Updating Media Information in the Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13535397/ios-updating-media-information-in-the-background)

I have an application that streams music from a server, I want to show the information of the now playing music when the user lock the iPhone screen actually I have found this code online:

```
Class playingInfoCenter = NSClassFromString(@"MPNowPlayingInfoCenter");

if (playingInfoCenter) {
    MPNowPlayingInfoCenter *center = [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter];
    NSDictionary *songInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              @"Artist", MPMediaItemPropertyArtist,
                              @"Title", MPMediaItemPropertyTitle,
                              @"AlbumTitle", MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle,
                              nil];
    center.nowPlayingInfo = songInfo;

}
```

But I don't know where to inject this code I tried to put it inside the IBAction method which is linked to the play button but it didn't work.
Is there any one can help me with that ? please.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you actually playing background audio?

Comment: @CodaFi : Yes I play a background audio.

Comment: @Till : In my app I use UIWebView to open the files so I'm not using the AVPlayer which is located in the question you mentioned my code to open these files here :     [myWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.website.com/file.mp3"]]];

Comment: @4slices still this part of that question is exactly what you were missing: `if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents)]){
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
        [self becomeFirstResponder];
        //These two steps are important if you want the user to be able to change tracks with remote controls (you'll have to handle the remote control events yourself).
    }`

Comment: where shall I insert this code? is it inside the play button action ? or some where else?

Comment: @4slices all of that is drafted in the quoted answer.... Please dude, do read that answer - yes, it is not a webview but the mechanics are the exact same.